# image button template?

Tags: wpf

I want Image button with two state(normal , mouse over). that button must change image with Mouse Over event trigger automatically. 
this image button must be a user control. Also i want to set image for each state form code in which form i use that user control.

Solution is using a template with "**Value Converter**" but i don't know how?

Comment: In your question and in several of your responses to answers you make several comments about needing a user control, but you don't explain what you mean by this.  From your comment about making a software phone it sounds like you need a template, not a user control.  Please give an example of what you would like to be able to write, and perhaps we will be able to help you.  Some hypothetical XAML would be nice.  In other words I suggest your framework as "I'd like to write something that looks like this: _________, how do I do it?"

Comment: I solve my problem 1 month ago. I will send solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### I found This on Code-project-Article(Cool example)

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/WPF_xaml_taskbar_window.aspx

First He create Wpf-Custom-control(you can create class inherit from Button like this)

```
 public class ImageButton : Button
{
    private string cornerRadius;
    public string CornerRadius
    {
        get { return cornerRadius; }
        set { cornerRadius = value; }
    }

    private string highlightBackground;
    public string HighlightBackground
    {
        get { return highlightBackground; }
        set { highlightBackground = value; }
    }

    private string pressedBackground;
    public string PressedBackground
    {
        get { return pressedBackground; }
        set { pressedBackground = value; }
    }
}
```

As second step you must Create template in resource-dictionary(here is code)

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Phone.Controls">

<ControlTemplate x:Key="ButtonTemplate" TargetType="{x:Type local:ImageButton}">
    <ControlTemplate.Resources>
        <Storyboard x:Key="MouseOverButton">
            <ThicknessAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="ButtonBackgroundBorder" 
                                Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Control.Margin)"
                                Duration="0:0:0.05" 
                                FillBehavior="Stop"
                                From="0,0,0,0" To="2,2,2,2" 
                                AutoReverse="True" />
        </Storyboard>
    </ControlTemplate.Resources>
    <Grid x:Name="ButtonOuterGrid">
        <Border x:Name="ButtonBackgroundBorder" 
                CornerRadius="{Binding Path=CornerRadius, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" 
                Background="{Binding Path=HighlightBackground, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" 
                BorderBrush="Black"
                BorderThickness="0.8"
                Opacity="0">
            <Border.BitmapEffect>
                <OuterGlowBitmapEffect GlowColor="#FFFFFFFF" GlowSize="2.75" Noise="0.20"/>
            </Border.BitmapEffect>
        </Border>
        <Border x:Name="ButtonEdgesBorder" CornerRadius="{Binding Path=CornerRadius, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"
                Opacity="1" 
                BorderBrush="Transparent"
                BorderThickness="0" />
        <Border x:Name="ButtonContentBorder" 
                CornerRadius="{Binding Path=CornerRadius, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" 
                Opacity="1" 
                BorderThickness="1">
            <ContentPresenter x:Name="ContentText"
                              Width="Auto" Height="Auto"

                              HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
                              VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
        </Border>
    </Grid>
    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
            <Trigger.Setters>
                <Setter Property="Opacity" TargetName="ButtonBackgroundBorder" Value="1"/>
                <Setter Property="TextElement.Foreground" TargetName="ContentText" Value="Black"/>
            </Trigger.Setters>
        </Trigger>
        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Grid.MouseEnter" 
                      SourceName="ButtonOuterGrid">
            <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource MouseOverButton}"/>
        </EventTrigger>
    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
</ControlTemplate>
<Style x:Key="ImageButton" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
    <Setter Property="Template" Value="{StaticResource ButtonTemplate}" />
</Style>
```

And this is last Step, in xaml file you must insert this custom-control

```
<ImageButton x:Name="btnConfigs"
                      Style="{StaticResource ImageButton}"
                      Width="25" Height="25"
                      VerticalAlignment="Top"
                      HorizontalAlignment="Right"
                      Margin="0,31.125,16.418,0">
            <Image x:Name="ImgConfigs"
                   Stretch="Fill"/>
        </ImageButton >
```

and in cs file do this

```
 this.ImgConfigs.Source="any imag-source"
```

also we can change this image-source on btnconfig-click event

#### With special thanks from Murray-Foxcroft for create that article

Answer (score 4):

Why must this image button be a user control? If a regular button with a new control template is fine, this should work:

```
<Button>
  <Button.Template>
    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
      <Grid>
        <Image Name="HoverImage" Source="hover_image.png" Visibility="Hidden" />
        <Image Name="DefaultImage" Source="default_image.png" />
      </Grid>
      <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
          <Setter TargetName="DefaultImage" Property="Visibility" Value="Hidden" />
          <Setter TargetName="HoverImage" Property="Visibility" Value="Visible" />
        </Trigger>
      </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
    </ControlTemplate>
  </Button.Template>
</Button>
```

Comment: this solution isn't good for me.

if i want use your solution i need make 30 image in my xaml.(15 button)

Comment: Then explain in more detail how you want to use this user control. Its not that obvious.

Comment: You could put the new control template in a style and use it for your 15 buttons

Comment: i want make a software phone with wpf.i want use that user corntrol for numeric buttons and some other buttons(config button,dial button)

Answer (score 0):

If you need a simple rollover effect, you don't need a template for it.. article below has a solution to it..

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/Resources/Detail.aspx?ResourceId=706
In this article user uses SolidColorBrush, you can use ImageBrush to set image as background of button.