# Parameters and ResourceDictionary

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, controltemplate

I created a ResourceDictionary in order to create a `ControlTemplate` for a `Button`.

**Here is my XAML code**

```
<ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}" x:Key="BoutonRessources">
<Button Width="32" Margin="0,0,7,0" Name="tbrClear" ToolTip="Clear" VerticalAlignment="Center" BorderThickness="0" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Background="Transparent" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center">
    <Button.Content>
        <Border>
            <Image Source="xRtDiva_XWPF_TBR_PREMIER.PNG_IMAGES.png" Height="18"/>
            <Border.Style>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type Border}">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent" />
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                            <Setter Property="Background">
                                <Setter.Value>
                                    <ImageBrush ImageSource="BoutonToolbarSelected.png"/>
                                </Setter.Value>
                            </Setter>
                            <Setter Property="Height"  Value="22"/>
                            <Setter Property="Width"  Value="32"/>
                        </Trigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
            </Border.Style>
        </Border>
    </Button.Content>
    <Button.Style>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}" >
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}" >
                        <ContentPresenter />
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </Button.Style>
</Button>
</ControlTemplate>
```

**When i use y template on my XAML code :**

```
<Button Template="{StaticResource BoutonRessources}">
```

I would like to give a parameter in order to set the picture for this Template "BoutonRessources".

**I tried to modify my code like this :**

```
<Button Template="{StaticResource BoutonRessources}">
   <Button.Content>
       <Border>
           <Image Source="myNewPicture.png" Height="18"/>
       </Border>
   </Button.Content>
</Button>
```

How can I personalize the picture of my button template please?

Thanks a lot :)

Comment: On what conditions do you want to display a different image?  Is an image the only content you want the button to display, or do you want to display other content such as text?

Comment: just an image :) i would like to be able to change the ="xRtDiva_XWPF_TBR_PREMIER.PNG_IMAGES.png" by "myPicture.png" like on my example :)

Answer (score 0):

In your button template, you have set the content of your button to a fixed value, so the assigning the Content on the button itself will do nothing.  Somewhere in your Template, you'll need to add a `ContentPresenter`.  If you do this, the `ContentPresenter` will be replaced by whatever you assign the content of the button.

What are you trying to accomplish?  Do you want the button to have 2 images or 1?  Perhaps look at this tutorial on creating templates (or one of the many others out there) and see if it helps: http://mark-dot-net.blogspot.com/2007/07/creating-custom-wpf-button-template-in.html

As a simple example, this minor modification to the template will add the image you add to the Content next to the image your manually assign in the template.  Notice how I've added a StackPanel and placed a `ContentPresenter` in the template.  This will be replaced with the content you assign to the button, and will show up to the right of the 'xRtDiva...' image your set in the template:

```
<ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}" x:Key="BoutonRessources">
        <Button Width="50" Margin="126.5,126,115.5,126" Name="tbrClear" ToolTip="Clear" VerticalAlignment="Center" BorderThickness="0" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Background="Transparent" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <Border>
                    <Image Source="xRtDiva_XWPF_TBR_PREMIER.PNG_IMAGES.png" Height="18"/>
                    <Border.Style>
                        <Style TargetType="{x:Type Border}">
                            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent" />
                            <Style.Triggers>
                                <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                                    <Setter Property="Background">
                                        <Setter.Value>
                                            <ImageBrush ImageSource="BoutonToolbarSelected.png"/>
                                        </Setter.Value>
                                    </Setter>
                                    <Setter Property="Height"  Value="22"/>
                                    <Setter Property="Width"  Value="32"/>
                                </Trigger>
                            </Style.Triggers>
                        </Style>
                    </Border.Style>
                </Border>
                <Border>
                    <ContentPresenter/>
                </Border>
            </StackPanel>

            <Button.Style>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}" >
                    <Setter Property="Template">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}" >
                                <ContentPresenter />
                            </ControlTemplate>
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                </Style>
            </Button.Style>

        </Button>
    </ControlTemplate>
```

I'm very confused about the `Button.Style` that you've assigned inside the button, however.  What is the purpose of that?

Comment: Hello, what i want ? I just want to be able to change the "xRtDiva_XWPF_TBR_PREMIER.PNG_IMAGES.png" :)

Comment: So do you want it to default to xRtDiva... and then if you set the content on the button itself it overrides that default?  If you are just looking to create a button that has a (customizable) image for content, I'd recommend looking at this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2635344/image-button-template

Comment: No, it don't override the default. Can you please give me the example, i don't understand the answer link you provide me :( Thanks a lot :)

Comment: I'm still not clear what you're trying to do.  Do you just want a button that will display an image?  If so, there's no need to use a `ControlTemplate`.  Do not assign the template and set the `Image` as the content of the button (like your previous comment, but remove the `Template`).

Comment: I want a button with an image, and with a background image on MouseEnter. I created a Template because i need to change the image on several case, and i don't dont want te replicate all my code for all case

Answer (score 0):

Why can't you just do the following?

```
<Button>
    <Image Source="firstImage.png" />
</Button>

<Button>
    <Image Source="secondImage.png" />
</Button>

<Button>
    <Image Source="thirdImage.png" />
</Button>
```

In this case if you want to change the button template, just put a ContentPresenter element where you want the image to be.

Comment: Can you please show me where insert the ContentPresenter on my template please ? Thanks a lot :)